# 'lein deploy clojars' does not ask for a passphrase

Tags: clojure, leiningen, gnupg

I want to deploy a Clojure library using Leiningen. I have done the following things:

- installed gpg
- created a gpg key-pair
- encrypted my Clojars credential into ~/.lein/credentials.clj.gpg
- installed gpg-agent
- installed [Keychain](https://github.com/funtoo/keychain)

When I call 'lein deploy clojars', I get the following output:

```
WARNING: please set :license in project.clj.
Could not decrypt credentials from ~/.lein/credentials.clj.gpg
gpg: can't query passphrase in batch mode
gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available

See `lein help gpg` for how to install gpg.
No credentials found for clojars
See `lein help deploy` for how to configure credentials.
Username:
```

I then uninstalled gpg, installed gpg2 and made a symlink from gpg to gpg2. When I now call 'lein deploy clojars', I get:

```
WARNING: please set :license in project.clj.
^CCould not decrypt credentials from ~/.lein/credentials.clj.gpg
pinentry-curses: no LC_CTYPE known - assuming UTF-8
pinentry-curses: no LC_CTYPE known - assuming UTF-8
pinentry-curses: no LC_CTYPE known - assuming UTF-8
pinentry-curses: no LC_CTYPE known - assuming UTF-8

gpg: signal Interrupt caught ... exiting

See `lein help gpg` for how to install gpg.
No credentials found for clojars
See `lein help deploy` for how to configure credentials.
Username:
```

After the warning, the command waits for an input, from which I can only exit by pressing ctrl-c.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do in order to deploy the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lein` made deploying to `clojars` as simple as possible with [lein-clojar plugin](https://github.com/ato/lein-clojars).

First, create `~/.lein/profiles.clj` file with the following content:

```
{:user {:plugins [[lein-clojars "0.9.1"]]}}
```

Unfortunately, you can't use passphrased keys with `lein-clojar` plugin, but you can generate new `ssh` key with `lein keygen` command. It will place new `ssh` key into `~/.leiningen/`, so it will be used only by `lein`.

After generating a key, `lein` will print its public part to the console. You should copy it to your `clojars` account.

At last, you can deploy your project with `lein push`.

Of course, you can deploy your project without this plugins using `lein deploy clojars` and any `ssh` or `pgp` key. Probably, it's possible to use pathphrased keys with `lein deploy clojars`, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Thank you very much. That works. Strange, that it is not possible. The [deploy guide](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/DEPLOY.md) suggests that it is possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but when I tried to deploy my own project to `clojars` using passphrased key `lein push` said it's not possible.

Comment: @Kocki I rechecked. Looks like it's `lein-clojars` who can't work with passphrased keys. So, probably, it's possible to deploy with passphrased key using `lein deploy clojars`.